# Magento: get all reviews on cms page filter review by attribute

Tags: magento

I want to add review on some specific page and filter review by attribute, like we want only review of product which brand is Samsung,

```
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection();
   $reviews->addStoreFilter( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
  ->addStatusFilter( Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED )
  ->setDateOrder()
  ->addRateVotes()
  ->load()
```

by using this code i am able to get review but how to filter review by attribute plase help

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection();
   $reviews->addStoreFilter( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
  ->addStatusFilter( Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED )
  ->setDateOrder()
  ->addRateVotes();

$reviews->getSelect()
->join(array('attr' => 'catalog_product_entity_int'), 'attr.entity_id = main_table.entity_pk_value', array('*'))
->where('attr.attribute_id = HARD_CODED_ATTRIBUTE_ID');
```

If your attribute has different type then just replace `catalog_product_entity_int` with EAV table of your attribute.

Hope this will help!